# Hive query to extract a column which has alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, presto

I have a requirement in which I need to extract the data based on a filter on a column and the filter would be to extract only alphanumeric values which means that it should contain at least one alphabet and a number for consideration.
For example if I have five numbers such as 333,abc,ab333,+33,+ab33 the output should have only ab333 and +ab33.
I was trying to implement this using the rlike function and the query is as below but this is giving all the records in the table.

**select column_name from table_name where column_name rlike '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$';**

I also tried a different approach by using the below query but in case of special characters such as + the below query gives the wrong result.

**select column_name from table_name where column_name not rlike '^[0-9]+$';**

Could anybody guide me regarding the mistake of if there is a different approach for this.

Comment: rlike '^\\+*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$'

Comment: @leftjoin thanks for the answer.I have tested the above  logic and it is covering some scenarios but in case the the record starts with a number it is not being considered.For example if the number is ab33 the logic is working fine but in case it is 33ab then the logic is not taking it in consideration. Also if the number starts or has any special character it is not being considered.For example if the number is +ab33 or ab33+ the logic is not considering the number.

Comment: Use `'^\\+?(?:[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9])[0-9a-zA-Z]*$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the answer.The logic is working fine as per my requirement.Could you please add it as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
RLIKE '^\\+?(?:[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9])[0-9a-zA-Z]*$'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\+?` - an optional `+` symbol
- `(?:[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9])` - one or more digits followed with a letter or one or more letters followed with a digit and then
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.